# Shrink and Group Column using Pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot, pivot-table

I'm having a SQL Table:

```
DECLARE @team TABLE (Department VARCHAR(20),TeamMember1 VARCHAR(50),TeamMember2 VARCHAR(50),TeamMember3 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @team VALUES('CRM','Tom', 'Harry', 'Rodger')
INSERT INTO @team VALUES('ERP','Boby', 'Simha', 'Wonder')
INSERT INTO @team VALUES('HR','Jack', 'John', 'Jim')

SELECT t.* FROM @team t
```

The Output of the Table should be

[image]

My **Expected Output** Should be

[image]

I referred many tutorial but I can't able to find a solution. So, kindly assist me... This a temporary table, I need to implement the same logic in my main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM @team
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES ('TeamMember1', TeamMember1)
         , ('TeamMember2', TeamMember2)
         , ('TeamMember3', TeamMember3)
) t(TeamName, TeamMember)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should know that storing the team members in separate columns is a bad data format.  The result you want is a better format.

A simple solution if you are learning SQL is `UNION ALL`:

```
select Department, TeamMember1 as TeamMember from @team union all
select Department, TeamMember2 as TeamMember from @team union all
select Department, TeamMember3 as TeamMember from @team;
```

However, other methods are more efficient, under some circumstances.  I would be inclined to use:

```
select t.Department, v.TeamMember
from @team t outer apply
     (values (TeamMember1), (TeamMember2), (TeamMember3)) v(TeamMember);
```

Comment: Where you defined the **`t.TeamName`** ?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan . . . The column name appears to be `department`.